# Yii простой вопрос по массивам и сессиям

Tags: массивы, php, yii, сессия

Видимо утро и я туплю, но наткнулся вроде как на простую задачу, а решение чего-то не дается. Суть: есть контроллер create (CRUD). При создании записи в БД он должен помещать id созданной записи в массив, а потом этот массив отдавать в сессию. Примерно это выглядит так:

```
 $session_array = array();
if($_POST['parent_id']==0){
        array_push($session_array, $model->id);
        }

        $_SESSION['basis_id']=$session_array;
```

Выше я опустил стандартные строки для создания строки экшена create.
Все бы ничего, но массив походу затирается и по `var_dump($_SESSION['basis_id']);` выдается только последний добавленный id, а не все, которые добавлял по очереди. Собственно подскажите, как можно получить в `$_SESSION['basis_id']` массив вида (1, 2, 3)

Comment: зачем вы работаете с суперглобальными массивами напрямую? Во фреймворке ведь есть инструменты для этого: [Yii::app()->request->getPost()][1], [Yii::app()->session][2]

 [1]: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#getPost-detail
 [2]: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession

Comment: @vanchester, в целом мысль верная, но конкретно для SESSION разницы никакой. Фреймворк устанавливает обработчики чтения-записи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по коду массив и будет перезатираться.

Вначале вместо:

```
$session_array = array();
```

нужно что-то вроде:

```
$session_array = isset($_SESSION['basis_id']) ? $_SESSION['basis_id'] : array();
```

Comment: Спасибо! То, что надо!